# I can't send data to the server using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, drag-and-drop

The situation is as follows: I upload a drag and drop image to the server. Everything would have been simpler, but first you need to embed the dropped image into the DOM tree, after which it can be removed from there, and the rest need to be sent to the server. At the drop event, I add the file itself and the picture className to the associative array. After the user is ready to send all the remaining pictures to the server, I add the files that have the classes of the remaining pictures as the key to the new array and form FormData of it. But the server does not receive files. Help!

code:

```
 var arr = new Map;
//create a associative array.
 dnd.addEventListener('drop', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            var image_ = e.dataTransfer.files;
```

.....

```
  //embed dropped image into the DOM tree
const text = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        if (text) {

            let img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = text;
            $('#container_').append(img);
        }
        else {

            const files = e.dataTransfer.files;
            [].map.call(files, file => {
                if (file.type.match(/^image/)) {

                    let reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = file => {


                        let img = document.createElement('img');

                        img.className = "droppedPhoto" + Math.random();
                        img.setAttribute("widt", "200");
                        img.setAttribute("height", "200");
                        img.src = file.target.result;


                        let div = document.createElement('div');
                        $('#container_').append(div);
                        $('#container_').children().last().append(img);

                        arr.set(img.className, image_);

  $('.sendPhotos > p > button').on('click', function () {
        checkData(arr);

    });

    function checkData(array) {
        var $arrOfImg = $('#container_ > div > img');
        var $newArrayOfData =[]; 
        for (var i = 0; i < $arrOfImg.length; i++) {
            if (array.has($arrOfImg[i].className)) {
            $newArrayOfData.push(array.get($arrOfImg[i].className));

            }
        }
        createFormData($newArrayOfData);
    }


    function createFormData(images) {
        var formImage = new FormData();
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {

            formImage.append(key, images[i]); 
        }

        uploadFormData(formImage);               
    }

    function uploadFormData(formData) {

        $.ajax({

            url: '@Url.Action("PhotoSessionInfo", "Home")',
            type: "POST",
            xhr: function () {
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                return myXhr;
            },
            data: formData,
            contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("success");
                $('#container_').html(response);

            }
        });
    }
```